# Importing to sql using ssis results to moving of data to the next column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

I am currently creating an ETL package that would import data from a .csv file to a database. My current problem is when I try to import data, some rows was not on the column where they should be. Please see my example below:

This is the correct output

```
Item No | Total Amount | No. of Lines | Time Received | Date Received
```

`1       | 575.85       |  1           |   13:01:35    |   2/16/16`

Some data turns to be like this:

`Item No | Total Amount | No. of Lines | Time Received | Date Received`

`NULL      1              NULL           1               13:01:35`

see, it moved to the column where it shouldn't be.
Hope you got what I mean :(
Please help me, I'm starting to get a headache because of this. :(
Thanks.

Comment: Did you manually check the csv file to see if the data structure in it was correct? Looks like you have a file with some missing data or data of the wrong type to be imported.

Comment: Yes, I checked all the data on my csv file.. I was wondering why some data are like this and some are not. Some data imports correctly,

Comment: In that case check the data types of the data against what the SSIS package is using. Also check for additional decimeters. IN csv it is really easy to get an additional comma that throws information to the wrong line afterwards

Comment: This happens everytime one column has a comma in it, the next column will automatically be affected.

Comment: Then your file is bad

Comment: No. It's not that my file is bad. I saw someone who had the same problem as mine. He has a comma on a column as well then the next columns were ruined everytime he tries to import data using ssis.

Comment: Yes because csv files cannot have internal commas in the data. That means the file is not acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if there are extra comma in the file. If there are then one of these options is this is what you need to do:

- Ask the provider use a different delimiter than comma. We insist on |
  as the delimiter.
- Ask the provider to use " as a text qualifier
- Ask the provider of the file to scrub out the commas for their data
  before sending it.
- Request the provider give you some other type of file as CSVs are the
  second worst kind to import for this very reason (Excel are the
  worst). A .txt file with a | delimiter is the least likely to cause
  this sort of import problem.
- Write a process that removes any rows with the wrong number of
  columns and puts them in exceptions and then create a process to
  clean that data and import it. This is the only real option if the
  provider cannot adjust his process to give you correct files. It will
  take considerably longer to do.If the provider is paying for the ETL
  development, it is not in his best interest financially to do this. Generally once I explain to a client how much more expensive this type of things is, they are more than will to fix their bad file.

Comment: thank you for this. I'll just ask my provider if the commas are on the right place where they should be or else, I'll just change the delimiter. Thank you.